# How to export database with mysqldump from local to remote server

Tags: mysql

I want to store the exported database from my local database to a remote server as below:

```
    mysqldump [options] > "root@my-ip:path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got answer

```
mysqldump [options] | ssh root@my-ip "cat > /home/db.sql"
```

https://serverfault.com/a/227954